# Starting a thread from a void method

Tags: c++, multithreading

Using C++, I would like to start a thread from a void method and then return before the thread may have finished. For example:

```
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void longFunc(){
  //stuff
}

void startThread(){
  thread t(longFunc);
}

int main(void){
  startThread();
  //lots of stuff here...
  return 0;
}
```

When the **`startThread()`** finishes, t tries to be deleted, and fails. How can I do this?

Comment: It doesn't try "to be deleted" it runs its destructor, and destroying a joinable thread is an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really want a fire-and-forget pattern, you can just detach from the thread:

```
void startThread(){
    thread t(longFunc);
    t.detach();
}
```

Or if you need to join the thread (which is most often a reasonable thing), you could simply return an `std::thread` object by value (thread wrappers are moveable):

```
std::thread startThread()
{
    return std::thread(longFunc);
}
```

Anyway, you may consider launching the thread through `std::async()` and returning a `future` object instead. This would be exception-safe, since exceptions thrown in the launched thread will be swallowed by the future object, and thrown again in the main thread when you invoke `get()` on it:

```
#include <thread>
#include <future>

void longFunc()
{
  //stuff
}

std::future<void> startThread()
{
    return std::async(std::launch::async, longFunc);
}

int main(void)
{
    auto f = startThread();
    //lots of stuff here...

    // For joining... (wrap in a try/catch block if you are interested
    //                 in catching possible exceptions)
    f.get();
}
```

Comment: Hey cool thanks for the answer so quickly. One question, in the first example what happens if the main finishes before the new thread, and the thread allocated some memory?

Comment: When the main thread exits the whole program exits, if other threads are still running and access any global data after `main()` exits it can lead to undefined behaviour.  You should try not to leave other threads running when `main()` exits

Comment: @Toby: As Jonathan said :)

Comment: Yeah - if you have problems with stopping the other threads, best to not let the app terminate by returning from main(), since that will run static dtors.  If this is an issue, you could call your OS 'TerminateProcess' API instead.