# How to start a thread from one object's method by calling another method?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have read various articles on C++ threading, among others [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multithreading-in-cpp/) article. I have also read [this quection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124206/starting-a-thread-from-a-void-method) but none of these has an answer for my need. In my project, (which is too complex to mention here), I would need something along the lines:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

class Simulate{
public:
    int Numbers[100][100];
    thread Threads[100][100];

    // Method to be passed to thread - in the same way as function pointer?
    void DoOperation(int i, int j) {
        Numbers[i][j] = i + j;
    }
    
    // Method to start the thread from
    void Update(){
        // Start executing threads
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                Threads[i][j] = thread(DoOperation, i, j);
            }
        }
        // Wait till all of the threads finish
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                if (Threads[i][j].joinable()) {
                    Threads[i][j].join();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
};

int main()
{
    Simulate sim;
    sim.Update();
}
```

How can I do this please? Any help is appreciated, and alternative solutions wellcomed. I am a mathematician by training, learning C++ for less than a week, so simplicity is pereferred. I desperately need something along these lines to make my research simulations faster.

Comment: I don't even know what you're trying to achieve. I think this is a classical "XY problem". Starting 10k threads is probably a bad approach for whatever task you're working on.

Comment: 10,000 threads will need 10,485,760,000 byte of (wired?) memory for the stacks, give or take depending on your operating system.  And unless you have a 10,000 core processor, the context switching will probably swamp any threading benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to call member functions and pass arguments is to use a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda):

```
Threads[i][j] = std::thread([this, i, j](){ this->DoOperation(i, j); });
```

The variables listed in `[]` are captured and their values can be used by the code inside `{}`. The lambda itself has a unique anonymous type, but can be implicitly cast to `std::function` which is accepted by `std::thread` constructor.

However, starting 100x100 = 10000 threads will quickly exhaust memory on most systems. Adding more threads than there are CPU cores does not improve performance for computational tasks. Instead it is a better idea to start e.g. 10 threads that each process 1000 items in a loop.

Comment: To deal with the very important point raised in the final paragraph look into [Thread Pools](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool)

Comment: Thank you so much - all of this really helped me!